# Ubuntu 18 and TinkPad Yoga 12: Suspend works only every other time, not hibernate at all

Tags: power-management

I gave up debugging hibernate, but I would like to have suspend working. Now on first suspend try, screen goes off, red led starts blinking, but PC is powered on and led keeps blinking forever. I have to press power button to wake it. On second suspend, the PC suspends correctly. On third suspend, it is same as on first. And so on. Has anyone had this behavior and fixed it?

Comment: Hi, I fixed both hibernate and suspend by switching up from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 18.10. if you're not open to that, ubuntu 19.04 releases 27 days from now and it will fix it too. Does this work as an answer for you? if yes I'll fill out the answer and you can mark me as answer to help other people find the solution.

Comment: I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 and it did not fix the problem. Suspend still works only on every second try.

Comment: "upgraded" or installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 breaks my filesystem during upgrade :-(

Comment: again I recommend install only. I'm very adamant about that. upgrade never works.

Comment: And is it possible to do a clean install and get settings back? If I restore my home directory I get back desktop (Gnome) settings and I can somehow restore all installed apps, correct? But some apps keep their settings outside home directory - cron, snapper... What to do with those?

Comment: you can save their settings individually. 90% of things are in /home though

Comment: Ubuntu 19 with kernel 5 broke suspend completely. I had to revert to kernel 4.18.0-16 to get it working, grrr..

Comment: ubuntu 19 ships with kernel 5, are you sure you're not talking about ubuntu 18?

Comment: Yes it is possible to start Ubuntu 19 with older kernel, so I get best of both worlds :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the small utility to automate the shutdown, logoff Lock computer, suspend and hibernate.  Change to sound as you see fit then compile and change chmod u+x filename.  Run it from terminal.  I rote a small script to double click and run in terminal.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define bold_on "\e[1m"
#define bold_off "\e[22m"
#define red_on "\033[31m"
#define reset "\033[0m"
#define yellow "\033[33m"
#define b_green "\033[1m\033[32m"
//======================================================================

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char answer;

  cout << b_green "\n\n Please make you choice? Any other key to quit the program. \n" reset << endl;

  cout << bold_on red_on "      S"  bold_off reset yellow" - Shutdown the Computer"  << endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      R"  bold_off reset yellow" - Restart the Computer"<< endl; 
  cout << bold_on red_on "      L"  bold_off reset yellow" - Logoff the Computer"<< endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      U"  bold_off reset yellow" - Suspend the Computer"<< endl;  
  cout << bold_on red_on "      H"  bold_off reset yellow" - Hybernate the Computer"<< endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      X"  bold_off reset yellow" - Lock the Computer \n\n" red_on;   


  cin >> answer;
    if( answer=='L' ) {
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("cinnamon-session-quit"); 

    } else if( answer=='R' ) {
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl reboot") ;             

    } else if (answer =='S') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl poweroff" );

    } else if (answer =='U') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl suspend");

    } else if (answer =='X') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("cinnamon-screensaver-command -l");

    } else if (answer =='H') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl hibernate");
     }
 }
```

And here is my script on my desktop.

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/dad/LRS
exit
```

Comment: systemctl hybernate shuts down my PC. There is lots of comments on that on the net and they involve heavy debugging which I tried almost all. Ubuntu can not be considered mature system if it can not properly use ACPI sleep states like Windows XP had - guess when - 17 YEARS AGO!

Comment: @Jan chill hibernate and sleep worked on ubuntu way before they did on XP, that's 17 versions! but at version 18 they messed with some settings that for a small group of people (you, me, others...) prevented them from working. let's just put things back into context here.

Comment: At version 19 with kernel 5 they messed it even more...